# Class to serialise/deserialise xml file

Tags: xml, vb.net

I need to deserialise the file into a vb.net object.

```
<ANIMALS>
  <ANIMAL NO = "1">Dog</ANIMAL>
  <ANIMAL NO = "2">Cat</ANIMAL>
  <ANIMAL NO = "3">Cow</ANIMAL>
  <ANIMAL NO = "4">Fish</ANIMAL>
</ANIMALS>
```

I have a class called clsANIMALS with a property returning a list of animals:

```
<Serializable()> _
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("ANIMALS")> _
Public Class clsANIMALS


<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("ANIMAL")> _
Public Property lstAnimal() As List(Of clsAnimal)
```

and a sub class called clsANIMAL having a property for the attribute "NO":

```
<Serializable()> _
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("ANIMAL")> _
Public Class clsANIMAL

<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute("NO")> _
Public Property iNoAnimal() As Integer
```

Can someone tell me how to deserialise the text such as Dog, Cat..?

Comment: Do you know about [`xsd.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.110).aspx)? You use `xsd /c file.xml` to generate `vb.net` classes to read the xml.

Comment: the answer given below was straight forward.thank u as well

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [XmlTextAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmltextattribute.aspx) to get values:

```
<Serializable()> _
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("ANIMAL")> _
Public Class clsANIMAL

    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute("NO")> _
    Public Property iNoAnimal() As Integer

    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlText()> _
    Public Property strName As String
End Class
```

Then you can deserialize the XML file and show the names using `strName`:

```
Dim stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead("Animals.xml")
Dim serializer = New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType([clsANIMALS]))
Dim animals As clsANIMALS = serializer.Deserialize(stream)
For Each animal In animals.lstAnimal
    Console.WriteLine(animal.strName)
Next
```