# How to structure a class to output an attribute and a simple string in the same XML node

Tags: xml, vb.net, xmlserializer

Given the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response Version="3">
  <Status StatusCode="Test">Some Value</Status>
</Response>
```

What is the correct way to structure the Status class so that the `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer` will parse the given XML into the status class correctly?

I am currently receiving this structure of XML from a third party and there is no chance that they will change the formatting.

My attempt at the response class looks like:

```vb
<XmlRoot(ElementName:="Response")> Public Class clsResponse
    <XmlAttribute(AttributeName:="Version"), DefaultValue(0)> Public Property intVersion() As Integer
    <XmlElement(ElementName:="Status", Type:=GetType(clsStatus), Order:=2)> Public Property strStatus() As clsStatus
End Class
```

And the status class:

```vb
<XmlRoot(ElementName:="Status")> Public Class clsStatus
    <XmlAttribute(AttributeName:="StatusCode")> Public Property strStatusCode() As String
    <XmlElement(ElementName:="Status", Order:=1)> Public Property strStatus() As String
End Class
```

Unfortunately this is resulting in the `strStatus` always being blank. All the examples I've been able to find online do not have a string value in the `<Status>` node, there are always sub nodes that make up the contents of the equivalent to the `<Status>` node.

Note: I've cut out a bunch of stuff from the XML and the code in an attempt to only include the relevant pieces. If I've cut out too much please let me know and I will supply any other needed information.

Comment: Take a look at [Using XmlSerializer to create an element with attributes and a value but no sub-element](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3524289/3744182) which says how to do it in c# using the `[XmlText]` attribute... and here's a vb.net version of the same answer: [Class to serialise/deserialise xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22589110/3744182).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Class to serialise/deserialise xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22589110/class-to-serialise-deserialise-xml-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add another class for Status element, since it contains more than one member.

```
Public Class Response

    <XmlAttribute> Public Version As Integer
    Public Status As Status

End Class

Public Class Status

    <XmlAttribute> Public StatusCode As String
    <XmlText> Public Text As String

End Class
```

You can use properties as well as rename members as needed and decorate them with output names in xml attributes.

Comment: Thanks. Changing the tag on `strStatus` from `XmlElement` to `XmlText` did the job.